# How to Convert a Date in String to match MySql date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I have a form where I save date as hidden field and pass the date value on form submit.
Now the problem is that when I am using this $date variable in MySQL query it does not match anything in the table.

My Query is:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM #__table WHERE zone_id = {$zid} AND user_id <> {$uid} AND date = {$date}";
```

The date field in the table is of data type 'DATE' and the date value stored in the `$date` variable is of `'STRING'` type.

Is there any way I can match them and get the result from the query?.

Comment: You'll have to show us what the date input and desired output is.

Comment: how does your PHP date string look like?

Comment: the date string looks like 2014-07-14 and the one stored in the database is 2014-07-14 but they differ in datatype

Comment: When you filter a date in a `where` clause in MySQL, you write the date like a string (e.g. `... where myDate='2014-07-14'`). I am not quite familiar with PHP, but, at least in Java, I can pass a string representation of a date to a prepared statement (yes, I use `setString()`) and it works perfectly. Try it with a string... It should work

Comment: You've got to put your date value in single quotes: `... AND date = '{$date}'";` otherwise 2014-07-14 will be evalutated to 1993 and that's not what you want. Better use prepared statements with parameters. This will take care of the sql injection vulnerability too.

Comment: @VMai Thank you Sir, the Query is working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $db = JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = 'DELETE FROM  #__table WHERE zone_id = '.$db->Quote($zid).' AND user_id <> '.$db->Quote($uid).' AND date = '.$db->Quote( $date );
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query();
```

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Click the `edited XX mins ago` link to see the revision history of a post.